# HTML, CSS, Flexible Layout

Tags: html, css

I've a dynamic rendered div layout, I don't know the number of divs, I tried to make layout flexible by using CSS `float` property and `display:flex;` property, but i'm failed in making this layout, please anybody have any idea to make this layout according to image attached below. I've also add code snippet for better understanding of my point. 
[image]

```css
.wrapper{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper > div{
 padding: 10px;
 width: 33%;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}
.wrapper > div > div{
 border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h4>Category 1</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h4>Category 2</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
             <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div>
        <div>
          <h4>Category 3</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div>
        <div>
          <h4>Category 4</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
             <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div>
        <div>
          <h4>Category 5</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div>
        <div>
          <h4>Category 6</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Subcategory</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your `html` and `css` code ? share it

Comment: @Bhargav, I've add code snippet, please check it now.

Comment: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: https://codepen.io/AdamBlum/pen/fwrnE

Comment: Thanks. @KrushnakantLadani ... It's good for images, but have some problems in text base boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have adjusted your padding and margin.
I would do something like this:

```
div {
margin: 10px auto; /* upper and bottom have a margin of 10px, to create some horizontal whitespace in between divs */
padding: 0;
}
```